# Proving a theorem of one sided limits

Tags: analysis, limits

I have the following theorem in my textbook but without a proof. Would someone be able to provide me with a detailed proof please. It would really help me out.

> "Let $A$ be contained in $\mathbb{R}$, $f:A \to \mathbb{R}$ and let $c$ in $\mathbb{R}$ be a cluster point of both the sets $A \cap (c,\infty)$ and $A \cap (-\infty,c)$. Then $\lim_{x \to c} = L$ iff $\lim_{x\to c^+} = L = \lim_{x \to c^-}$."

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

If $A\subseteq\mathbb R$ and $c$ is cluster point of $A\cap(-\infty,c)\subseteq\mathbb R$ and of $A\cap(c,\infty)$ then by definition:

$L=\lim_{x\to c+}f(x)\iff\forall\epsilon>0\exists\delta>0\text{ s.t. }x\in(c,c+\delta)\cap A\implies|L-f(x)|<\epsilon$

$L=\lim_{x\to c-}f(x)\iff\forall\epsilon>0\exists\delta>0\text{ s.t. }x\in(c-\delta,c)\cap A\implies|L-f(x)|<\epsilon$

$L=\lim_{x\to c}f(x)\iff\forall\epsilon>0\exists\delta>0\text{ s.t. }x\in(c-\delta,c+\delta)\cap A-\{c\}\implies|L-f(x)|<\epsilon$

Let it be that $L=\lim_{x\to c+}f(x)$ and $L=\lim_{x\to c-}f(x)$ and $\epsilon>0$.

Then  $\delta_1,\delta_2>0$ exist with $|L-f(x)|<\epsilon$ for every $x\in(c,c+\delta_1)\cap A$ and every $x\in(c-\delta_2,c)\cap A$.

Then consequently $|L-f(x)|<\epsilon$ for every $x\in(c-\delta,c+\delta)\cap A-\{c\}$ when $\delta=\min(\delta_1,\delta_2)>0$.

So we conclude that $L=\lim_{x\to c}f(x)$

Conversely let $L=\lim_{x\to c}f(x)$ and $\epsilon>0$.

Then $\delta>0$ exists with $|L-f(x)|<\epsilon$ for every $x\in(c-\delta,c+\delta)\cap A-\{c\}$.

Then automatically $|L-f(x)|<\epsilon$ for every $x\in(c-\delta,c)\cap A$ and $|L-f(x)|<\epsilon$ for every $x\in(c,c+\delta)\cap A$.

So we conclude that $L=\lim_{x\to c-}f(x)$ and $L=\lim_{x\to c+}f(x)$.